# RuntimeError when building CSS from SCSS files of Foundation-sites with Django-pipeline

Tags: python, django, sass, zurb-foundation, django-pipeline

My issue is in the same context as [Django-Bower + Foundation 5 + SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21421564/2228912). I'm trying to compile `foundation` from `scss` to `css`. The problem is that I'm encountering the following `RuntimeError`:

```sh
/home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:287:in `watch_or_update': File /home/hakim/github/myquotes/static/quotes/app.css doesn't exist. (RuntimeError)
    Did you mean: sass --update /home/hakim/github/myquotes/static/quotes/app.scss:/home/hakim/github/myquotes/static/quotes/app.css
    from /home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in `process_result'
    from /home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
    from /home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
    from /home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/sass:22:in `load'
    from /home/hakim/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
```

The static files are stored in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`.

Here is the relevant part of my `setting.py`:

```py
# Manage static files with pipeline 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage' 

# Where to generate CSS from SCSS
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Specify SCSS files to be compiled to CSS
PIPELINE = {
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'librairies': {
            'source_filenames': (
                 'quotes/app.scss',
             ),
             'output_filename': 'quotes/app.css',
         },
     },
     'COMPILERS': (
         'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',
     ),
     'SASS_ARGUMENTS': "--trace --update -I '%s'" % os.path.join(
         BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT,
         'bower_components',
         'foundation',
         'scss'
    ),
}
```

`app.scss` contains only `@import 'foundation';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem above which was caused by me forgetting to consider the hierarchy of folders in `app.scss` (when importing foundation). By putting this file in `/static` with the downloaded `foundation-sites` and setting its content like below, I managed to make it work:

```sass
@import 'foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss';
@import 'foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';

@include foundation-everything;
```